# Introductory Analysis Question

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I have a given question. It asks to prove a statement. However I can find a counterexample. I assume that the statement is true. My problem is I could not figure out my mistake in my example. I hope someone could find it. Here is the given statement, and my setup fallows it

> *For any real number $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ choose a positive real number $a_\lambda > 0$.* 
>   *Show that the subset A below is unbounded* 
>  $ A = \{a_{\lambda_1} + ... +a_{\lambda_k} | k \in \mathbb{N}, \lambda_1,
>  ... , \lambda_k \in \mathbb{R} $ *are all distinct*.$\}$.
>   *What if the indices λ were from integers but not from reals?*

I defined $ \lambda_i $ and $ a_\lambda $ as below:

$a_\lambda=
\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{\lambda^2}&\text{if}\, \lambda< -1\\
 1&\text{if}\, -1 \leq x <1 \\
     \frac{1}{\lambda^2}&\text{if}\, 1 \leq \lambda
\end{cases} $

$ \lambda_i=i $ , $ \forall i \in \mathbb{N}  $

With the function $a_\lambda$ for any real number $\lambda$ I choosed a real number $a_\lambda$. 
For $k=1$, $a_{\lambda_1} = 1$ and $a_{\lambda_1}:= A_1 \in A$ 
For $k=2$, $a_{\lambda_1} + a_{\lambda_2}  = 1 + \frac{1}{2^2}$ and $ (a_{\lambda_1} + a_{\lambda_2}):= A_2 \in A$ 
For $k=3$, $a_{\lambda_1} + a_{\lambda_2} + a_{\lambda_3} = 1 + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2}$ and $ (a_{\lambda_1} + a_{\lambda_2} + a_{\lambda_3}):= A_3 \in A$ 
.
.
.

So $A$ is a subset of real numbers. For each natural number it has a unique member. Morover if $n<m$ then $A_n<A_m$.

Now lets consider the region defined as: 
$$ R=1+ \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_{1}^{b}\frac{1}{\lambda^2}d\lambda = 1 + \lim_{b \to \infty} (\frac{-1}{\lambda}|_1^b)= 1 + \lim_{b \to \infty} (1 -\frac{1}{b}) = 2 $$ 
Since $\sum_{\lambda=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lambda^2} < R = 2$, I conclude that A is bounded.

Comment: Choose $\lambda_k = 1+\frac 1k$ to see that the set in your example is unbounded. Note that $a_{\lambda_k}>\frac 12$ for $k\ge 3$.

Comment: I find your argument hard to read, so I don't know where the error might be. I think the question should have been written without the confusing notation. What it asks you to show is that an uncountable set of positive real numbers must have unbounded finite sums but that a countable set of positive numbers can have bounded finite sums.

Answer (score 1):

What you showed was that there exists an infinite number of elements of $A$ which are smaller than $2$.

What you did not show (and is also not true) is that **all** elements of $A$ are smaller than $2$.

---

For example, let's take your selection of $a_{\lambda}$. From it, I can select $\lambda_1 = 1.1, \lambda_2 = 1.01, \lambda_3=1.001$ and so on, and produce $a_{\lambda_1} = \frac{1}{1.1}, a_{\lambda_2} = \frac{1}{1.01}, \dots$.

Thus, we can see that $B_1 = a_{\lambda_1}, B_2=a_{\lambda_1} + a_{\lambda_2}, B_3=a_{\lambda_1} + a_{\lambda_2}+a_{\lambda_3}$ and so on are all elements of $A$. Also, you may notice that $B_2 > 2\cdot a_{\lambda_1}$, and $B_3 > 3\cdot a_{\lambda_1}$, and it can be generally shown that $B_k > k\cdot a_{\lambda_1}$, and therefore, $A$ is unbounded.

---

More strictly, what I have done above is

1. I define $\lambda_i=1+10^{-i}$.
2. I define $B_k = \sum_{i=1}^k a_{\lambda i}$.
3. By definition of $A$, we know that $B_k\in A$.
4. From the construction of $B_k$, we see that $B_k > k\cdot a_{\lambda_1}$.
5. From the fact that $$\lim_{k\to\infty} B_k = \lim_{k\to\infty}k\cdot a_{\lambda_1} = \infty,$$ we see that the set $\{B_i|i\in\mathbb N\}\subseteq A$ is not bounded.
6. From that, we conclude $A$ is not bounded, since it contains an unbounded set.

Comment: It seems that B is a set that is not equal to A(the one I generated). Moreover B is not convergent. But does this make  all sets defined in the statement bounded?

Comment: @SEL I did not construct $B$. I constructed a series of numbers, $B_1, B_2,\cdots$, such that for all $i$, $B_i$ is an element of $A$. In other words, if you want to define $B=\{B_1, B_2,B_3,\dots\}$ (or, more strictly, $B=\{B_i|i\in\mathbb N\}$), then $B\subseteq A$. Indeed, $B\neq A$, but that is irrelevant. If a subset of $A$ is unbounded, then clearly, $A$ is also unbounded.

Comment: @SEL $A$ includes all possible sums of $a_{\lambda_1} + a_{\lambda_2}+\cdots a_{\lambda_k}$, where $\lambda_i$ are distinct real numbers. You did not list **all** possible sums, you only listed *some* of them. I listed some other ones. You limited your selection of $\lambda_i$ to natural numbers, but the original question does no such thing.

Comment: If I have used all the natural numbers to enumerate the real numbers (or continuing to enumerate them endlessly)  in the set that I've constructed then how could it be possible that, A include the B's that you mentioned.

Comment: @SEL Where, in the question, does it say that you are allowed to limit the set of all possible values of $\lambda$? Where does it say that $\lambda=1.01$ is not allowed?

Comment: Thank you very much. I am getting closer to the point. My question is now: Is A well defined? Can I say that C is the set off all cars in London which will possibly pass over the Tower Bridge.

Comment: $\lambda$ s are need to be counted with natural numbers, it is given. And I prefer first count all the natural number which are real numbers.

Comment: @SEL The lambdas are only counted with the natural numbers in the second part of the question, not the first.

Comment: In the question it says that " For any real number $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ choose a positive real number $a_\lambda >0$". It is a simply a function from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $. Then in the set builder notation, it says ( as far as I understand) choose countably many item from the range of that function which are $a_\lambda$'s, add them together and put the sum in the set A. And there are no restrictions about how to choose these real numbers from the image. I prefer the way that makes the set bounded. Of course there are other possibilities, but I am not interested with them, should I?

Comment: @SEL The set builder notation says nothing about choosing *countably* many items. Where did you see *countably* written anywhere in the first part of the question? The set $A$ is the set of all numbers which can be written as $a_{\lambda_1}+\cdots+a_{\lambda_k}$ for *some* selection of $\lambda_i$. Therefore, your (bounded) set is a subset of $A$, but my unbounded set is also a subset of $A$, as there exists some selection of $\lambda_i$ for which the sums of $a_{\lambda_i}$ are equal to elements of my set $B$.

Comment: Natural numbers are countable. Aren't they?

Comment: @SEL Yes, so? There is nothing in the question that suggests you are only allowed to pick $\lambda_i$ from the set of natural numbers...

Comment: I did not say anything like that eighter. I said countably many real numbers, because we are enumerating them with natural numbers.

Comment: @SEL Where in the first part of the question does it say we are only allowed to pick $\lambda_i$ out of a set of countably many real numbers? Look, I'm getting a little frustrated here. The question you cite clearly suggests the set *is* unbounded. In other words, I am right. You, instead of accepting you are wrong, seem intent on contradicting me, even when you have no basis to do so. Why?

Comment: I did not violate any given rule in the question and I construct a bounded set. As I said in the beginning I should have made a mistake or the setup in the queation is not correct. If you know where I am wrong and show it to me I will be appreciated, If you are tired just do not open this page. You solved a question you got your points or whatever, you dont need to convince me to anything. I am seeking the contradiction. I am not interested with anything else.

Comment: "I did not violate any given rule in the question and I construct a bounded set.". No, you didn't violate any rule, but you also did not construct the set $A$. *That* is where you are wrong. Your mistake is thinking that because the set *you* constructed is bounded, that $A$ is bounded. It is not. $A$ is unbounded, as my answer clearly shows. You only constructed a subset of $A$, as I said for the fifth time now. If you refuse to listen to me, that's fine by me, but I am puzzled as to why you would ask a question if you are clearly not interested in hearing what the answer is.

Comment: ok I will read all above again. I hope you are right.

Comment: @SEL The point I made in my last comment is actually the point I wrote in the first two sentences of my answer.

Comment: I am in contradiction with $\aleph_0 < \aleph_1$. I assume that I count all the real numbers and no other left. Thanks alot.

Comment: @SEL Even if you assumed you counted all the real numbers, it is clear that you did *not* count $1.1$, $1.01$, $1.001$, and so on. And yes, in general, it is impossible to count all real numbers.

Comment: I will never assume that and nobody could :). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum